# Resharper and .less files - does "go to file member" navigation work on less files?

Tags: .net, resharper, less

I cannot get the ReSharper **Go to file member** navigation to work on .less files. 
Simply does not display any of the members. Works fine on css and all other files - just not the .less files.

Can anyone confirm it works OK for them.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't appear that way: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/06/preventing-items-from-being-analyzed-in-resharper/

> With the imminent release of ReSharper 6, and support for JavaScript as well as CSS, we’ve had a few people ask us how to prevent ReSharper 6 from detecting issues in certain files that are not supported, for instance .less.

Comment: Thanks @Dave - did see that, but was curious if there was a way to tell Resharper to treat the file as a css file?

Comment: You might be able to hack the registry to identify .less files as CSS but this is probably of limited value since .less files aren't quite CSS so you'll just end up with a load of validation issues anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Worth mentioning that support is still not possible with R# 7, but that their [SDK enables adding support for additional languages](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/07/resharper-7-whats-inside/):

> **SDK enables developing ReSharper support for new languages.** This is not your typical selling feature, even more so that it’s not something that comes out of the box, but in actual fact in you take a look at how many people vote for F#, CoffeeScript, or LESS support in ReSharper, you’ll see that this one has a potential to make ReSharper a great tooling foundation for polyglot development on the .NET platform.

The [feature request on their issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-215161) currently has 251 votes.

**Please weigh in if this is something you'd like to see** in a future version of R#.

Comment: please register on their tracker and upvote it for native support. it's taking long enough for them to finally do it. give them a reason to work on it sooner than later